# Is unitarity equivalent to linearity plus conservation of the norm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, unitarity, normalization, linear-systems

Unitarity is the condition that the inner product in the Hilbert space is preserved.  But if you suppose that the norm of any state is already preserved, then does unitarity follow from linearity?  For example, if you have two vectors $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$, then initially the norm of their sum is

$$\langle a+b|a+b \rangle$$
$$= \langle a|a \rangle + \langle a|b \rangle + \langle b|a \rangle + \langle b|b \rangle$$

and since their individual norms don't change, it becomes after evolution by a linear operator

$$\langle \hat H(a+b)|\hat H(a+b)\rangle$$
$$= \langle \hat H(a) + \hat H(b)|\hat H(a) + \hat H(b)\rangle$$
$$= \langle\hat H(a)|\hat H(a)\rangle + \langle\hat H(a)|\hat H(b)\rangle + \langle\hat H(b)|\hat H(a)\rangle + \langle\hat H(b)|\hat H(b)\rangle$$
$$= \langle a|a \rangle + \langle\hat H(a)|\hat H(b)\rangle + \langle\hat H(b)|\hat H(a)\rangle + \langle b|b \rangle$$

But since the norm of the sum can't change either, we have

$$\langle \hat H(a)|\hat H(b) \rangle + \langle \hat H(b)|\hat H(a) \rangle
= \langle a|b \rangle + \langle b|a \rangle$$

Since the inner product is Hermitian, we also know that the pair of terms on either side are complex conjugates, hence

$$2\mathfrak{Re}(\langle \hat H(a)|\hat H(b) \rangle) = 2\mathfrak{Re}(\langle a|b \rangle)$$

Clearly, this alone does not *require* $\langle \hat H(a)|\hat H(b) \rangle$ to equal $\langle a|b \rangle$... but is there perhaps some additional reasoning that forces the equality?

Comment: Your definition of unitarity is incomplete. A linear map is unitary if it is surjective and preserves the inner product. The latter does not imply the former in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If norm of *any* state is preserved, then the inner product is preserved as well. You have already shown that the real part of $\langle a|b\rangle$ is preserved. Doing the same for $|a\rangle + i|b\rangle$ will show that the imaginary part is preserved as well.